# Force couchbase to update view index while integration testing

Tags: integration-testing, couchbase, couchbase-view

I'm looking to integration test my Couchbase implementation and i'm running into a problem with the eventually-consistent nature of Couchbase.  In production, it's perfectly ok for my data to be stale, but at test time i'd like to insert some data and then verify that i'm getting it back via my various services.  This doesn't work if the data is stale because my test expectations can't account for that.

I can work around this by setting staleState to false in the Couchbase client, but that means that every test i have is going to trigger a rebuild of the indexes and increases their running time.

Is there a way to force Couchbase to trigger a one-time rebuild the indexes for a design doc?  Essentially, i'd like to upload all of my test data, trigger a rebuild and then execute my test cases.

Also if there's a better pattern for integration testing with Couchbase, i'd love to hear it.

Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase will only rebuild the view indexes when stale=false is set if there is actually more data that needs to go into the index. Your first stale=false may take some time, but the rest of the calls should be fast even with stale=false set as long as you're not putting more data into your cluster.

For all of the subsequent calls there will a small (millisecond or smaller) delay due to the index checking to make sure it is up to date. If you don't want this you can just run the queries with stale=true and again as long as you're not inserting any more data you should get the correct results.

The last thing to note is that view index builds are incremental so they never rebuild the entire index.